# Creating identity matrix with CUDA

Tags: cuda

Hi i try to create an identity matrix with CUDA but the output is just : zeros

```
__global__ void initIdentityGPU(int *devMatrix, int numR, int numC) {

    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;

    int offset = x * y;

    for (int i = 0; i < x ; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < numR; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                devMatrix[offset] = 1;
            else
                devMatrix[offset] = 0;

        }

    }

}
```

Why only it puts 0s ?

Comment: `offset` is set only once at the beginning of function, hence, you are assigning 0s and 1s to the same position.

Comment: so what is the right form

Comment: You probably shouldn't have any loops - each thread will just deal with one array element, typically, but only you know how you have structured your program.

Comment: i call that function like that <<<grid,1>>>(parameters) so each thread just deal with one array element

Comment: OK - so just get rid of the for loops.

Comment: <<<grid,1>>> causes wasting of computational capacity of your GPU since there is just one thread in each warp and CUDA behaves as SIMD architecture mainly on warp level.

Comment: i know but instructors expects that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way how to do it is:

```
__global__ void initIdentityGPU(int **devMatrix, int numR, int numC) {
    int x = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(y < numR && x < numC) {
          if(x == y)
              devMatrix[y][x] = 1;
          else
              devMatrix[y][x] = 0;
    }
}
```

and you launch it as:

```
dim3 blockDim(BLOCK_DIM_X, BLOCK_DIM_Y);  
dim3 gridDim((numC + BLOCK_DIM_X - 1) / BLOCK_DIM_X, (numR + BLOCK_DIM_Y - 1) / BLOCK_DIM_Y);
initIdentityGPU<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(matrix, numR, numC);
```

It simply runs as many threads as matrix cells, each thread obtains the coordinates of its cell and in a case the cell is in the diagonal of matrix it assigns `1` or `0` otherwise. Note the code is untested.

Comment: i need the way i do. I need to set one offset

Comment: In that case `offset = y * numC + x`.

Comment: so what is the offset for putting 0s

Comment: offset = y * numC + x for putting 1s so what is offset for 0s?

Comment: You calculate `offset`, depending on coordinates `x` and `y`, for all threads. Afterwards, `if(x == y) {devMatrix[offset] = 1;} else  {devMatrix[offset] = 0;}`